# How to capture mouse click events from console in eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, events, console, eclipse-plugin, mouse

I'm developing an eclipse plugin. It writes some lines in a console. In order to select a line displayed in the console, I’m trying to capture mouse double click event from that console.

The console has been implemented by following this eclipse [FAQ](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_write_to_the_console_from_a_plug-in%3F). `MessageConsole` or `IconsoleView` classes doesn‘t seem to provide a methode to add a listener with an `SWT.MouseDoubleClick` event.

Is there any way to capture a mouse event from a console and then read the selected line ?

Comment: Do you really need a console? This is a lot easier to do with a plain view containing something like a `StyledText` control.

Answer (score 0):

The `MessageConsole` doesn't know anything about how the data is displayed, it is the `TextConsoleViewer` that deals with that.

To access the console viewer you need to use a custom message console - extending `MessageConsole` or `TextConsole` and overriding `createPage` to create your own console page extending `TextConsolePage`.

The console page needs to override the `createViewer` method to create your own text console viewer extending `TextConsoleViewer`.

In the viewer you can override the `mouseDoubleClick` method to receive the double clicks.

For an example see the Eclipse JDT `JavaStackTraceConsole`, `JavaStackTraceConsolePage`, and `JavaStackTraceConsoleViewer` classes.

```java
public class JavaStackTraceConsole extends TextConsole {

    ...

    @Override
    public IPageBookViewPage createPage(IConsoleView view) {
        return new JavaStackTraceConsolePage(this, view);
    }
}
```

```java
public class JavaStackTraceConsolePage extends TextConsolePage {
   
    ...

    @Override
    protected TextConsoleViewer createViewer(Composite parent) {
        return new JavaStackTraceConsoleViewer(parent, (JavaStackTraceConsole) getConsole());
    }
}
```

```java
public class JavaStackTraceConsoleViewer extends TextConsoleViewer {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it works fine. I just had to managed the mouse event in another way because overriding the `mouseDoubleClick` method didn’t work. Here is my code :

```java
    public class MyTextConsoleViewer extends TextConsoleViewer {
    
    
        public MyTextConsoleViewer(Composite parent, MyMessageConsole console) {
            super(parent, console);
            StyledText styledText = getTextWidget();
            MouseListener listener = new MouseListener() {
                
                @Override
                public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
                
                @Override
                public void mouseDown(MouseEvent arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    
                }
                
                @Override
                public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent event) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    IDocument document = console.getDocument();
                    try {
                        int currentLine = document.getLineOfOffset(styledText.getOffsetAtLocation(new Point (event.x, event.y)));
                        IRegion lineInfo = document.getLineInformation(currentLine);
                        System.out.println(document.get(lineInfo.getOffset(), lineInfo.getLength()));
                    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            styledText.addMouseListener(listener );
            
            
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    
        public MyTextConsoleViewer(Composite parent, TextConsole console,
                IScrollLockStateProvider scrollLockStateProvider) {
            super(parent, console, scrollLockStateProvider);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }
    
        
        @Override
        public void mouseDoubleClick(MouseEvent e) {
            System.out.println("This even doesn't work!");
        }
        
        
    }
```